# 二番目に大きい数字を出力するプログラムの作成方法

Tags: c

二番目に大きい数字を出力するプログラムを実装したいのですが、コンパイルはできるものの、コンパイル結果が入力した数字によっておかしくなってしまうケースがあります。

というのは、始めに端末に以下のように入力したところ、正常に結果が出たと思われたのですが、

```
$ ./a.out
データの個数入力:　4
1 番目? 1
2 番目? 4
3 番目? 7
4 番目? 6
二番目に大きい値は6です。
```

データの数を増加させたところ、結果が期待しているのとは違うように出力されました。

```
$ ./a.out
データの個数入力:　6
1 番目? 2
2 番目? 3
3 番目? 10
4 番目? 4
5 番目? 5
6 番目? 1
二番目に大きい値は6です。
```

おそらくは、関数`secondMax`の部分がおかしいのではないかとは思うのですが、どの部分がおかしいのかがわかりませんでした。
一番大きい数や、一番小さい数を出力させるプログラムは何度も作成したことがあるので、実装方法はわかるのですが、二番目に大きい数は初めてなので、変な箇所がありましたらご回答よろしくお願いします。

```
#include<stdio.h>

void readIntArray(int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i=i+1) {
        printf("%d 番目? ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
}

int secondMax(int a[],int size)
{
    int i,max,max2;
    
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(a[i]>max)
            max=a[i];
    }
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if((max>a[i] && a[i]>max2))
            max2=a[i];
    }
    return max2;
}
         
int main()
{
    int data[1024],num,second;
    printf("データの個数入力:　");  scanf("%d",&num);
    readIntArray(data,num);
    
    second=secondMax(data,num);
    
    printf("二番目に大きい値は%dです。\n",second);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 先日の質問 [入力ファイルに書いてある数字を昇順結果がすべて0になってしまいます](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/70962/) の `sort()` 関数を修正して利用する方が良いかと思いますが…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`secondMax`関数：

- `for`文のループ変数`i`の初期値は0でしょう。
- `max`と`max2`とは初期値を持っていないまま、数値比較を行ってしまいました。入力データは全て正数限りですか。そうでしたら、二つも0に初期化しましょう。

最も汎用的な方法はソートです。

Comment: `int i,max=a[0],max2=0` で初期化しておくと最初の for loop は `for(i=1;...)` でよいかと思います。

Comment: @metropolis `max=a[0]`にすることで、`max`を算出用の`for`文は現在のまま利用できますが、`max2=0`で、`max2`の`for`文はまた問題ありそうです。特に、全部の入力データは負数の場合...

Comment: データが `1 2 2` のとき「２番目」が何なのかは事前の案件出しが必要で、それ抜きに一気にコード化しようとしているのがどうにも気になる

Comment: Lightさん　ご指摘通りにi=0,max=a[0],max2=a[0]を初期化したことにより、きちんと期待したコンパイル結果が出力されました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: @user41837 I still think this is not a good idea, and may face some limitation (maybe it's because of my poor knowledge about C and algorithm). Regardless what kind of data you want to get (the max. one, or another), sorting the input data first, and then picking the one that meets your requirement might be more universal method.